# icprog with wine on ubuntu can't see ports

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wine

hi im trying to pic programming with Icprog.i can't find a Linux alternative so im using wine and install Icprog.its working but can't see com ports.i need ft232bl driver for my circuit for Usb to serial but i don't know how to can make.please help..

Comment: Close voters. Crafting answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than jumping through hoops trying to get a Windows program working under wine, why not use an open source Microchip PIC programmer for the USB port designed to run under Ubuntu? Take a look at http://usbpicprog.org/ and see if the Ubuntu version available [here](https://launchpad.net/~fransschreuder1/+archive/ubuntu/usbpicprog-stable) will fit your needs.